# Bootstrap menu not working after the Bootstrap Dialog is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble on my project. I just incorporated the bootstrap menu and everything is working fine. But then I arrived to a situation where I need to call the **BootstrapDialog.show()** method. The dialog appears then, but when I closed the dialog, my menu is not working anymore, the sub menu's under my main menu are not showing. Does anyone encounter the same problem.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do you have any code to show? That would be helpful! :)

Comment: jq("#ddpromo").change(function(){
  var id = jq("select option:selected").val();
  var url = "<?= base_url('/myurl/" + id + "') ?>";
  var elId = "#myModalContent";
  BootstrapDialog.show({
   type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS,
   title: 'Bonus Product',
   message: jq("<div>").load(url),
   closable: true,
   closeByBackdrop: false,
   closeByKeyboard: false,
   buttons: [{
    label: 'Close',
    action: function(dialog){
     dialog.close();
    }
   }]
  });
 });